# Express GET route is not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, routes

I have this route:

```js
// FIXME: This rotes has a unknown bug
router.get('/unverified', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const unverifiedUsers = await User.find(
      { is_verified: false, is_admin: false },
      { name: 1, code: 1, email: 1, gender: 1 }
    );
    return res.status(200).json(unverifiedUsers);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send({ error });
  }
});
```

And I use it like this:

```js
app.use('/api/users', userRoute);
```

Everytime I go to `http://localhost:5000/api/users/unverified` I got this:

```js
{
    "error": {
        "stringValue": "\"unverified\"",
        "kind": "ObjectId",
        "value": "unverified",
        "path": "_id",
        "reason": {}
    }
}
```

It's strange to me because the other routes work perfectly and that error doesn't give me a reason.

Comment: Is that error from your catch object in your question, or a catch all error you have? If the one in the answer, then your error is inside the `try` block and there’s nothing wrong with your route... try simply do `res.json({hi:"there”})` - [here is a repo](https://github.com/balexandre/so65351733) that I did for other question, with what you’re mentioning working...

Comment: @balexandre I even tried to console.log() outside the try/catch, and it didn't show up. I also deleted the mongoose logic, and it still...

Comment: We need to know for sure if the error you show is coming from your `catch` block or from some other error mechanism in your server? A few `console.log()` statements in appropriate places will easily answer that question. Put one at the start of your route (before the `try`). Put one right after the `await User.find()`. Put one in the `catch`.  Tell us which log statements get hit. FYI, this is elemental debugging/troubleshooting and should generally be something you do before posting here as part of your own troubleshooting. You can also use breakpoints in the debugger to learn this same info.

Comment: @Phil Before the `try` keyword. Apparently, the callback doesn't execute

Comment: Do you have any other routes defined that might match? For example `/api/users/:username`

Comment: [Ok so I put these `console.log()`](https://i.imgur.com/btJ9kAl.png)
In the console, neither of the three appear when I GET to that route with postman.

Comment: @Phil Well... I have a `/api/users/:id` route

Comment: That's your problem then. You need to define the specific routes like `/unverified` first. I'm sure there's a duplicate post around here somewhere

Comment: So the variable routes go below the specific ones?

Answer (score -2):

you try to go to the path name called "unverified" but you don't have a route to it

you have to do like that

```
router.get('/api/users/unverified', async (req, res) => {
try {
const unverifiedUsers = await User.find(
  { is_verified: false, is_admin: false },
  { name: 1, code: 1, email: 1, gender: 1 }
);
 return res.status(200).json(unverifiedUsers);
} catch (error) {
return res.status(400).send({ error });
}
});
```

also you need to have an route to it with same path name

```
app.use('/api/users/unverified', userRoute);
```

Comment: I think tou're misunderstanding the OP's code.  `userRoute` is a router with the `/unverified` route on it.  And, `app.use('/api/users', userRoute);` then makes a proper route for `/api/users/unverified`.